# knitr html virus detected

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, knitr

I have an rmd that I'm using knitr to generate an html file from. When I try to attach to an email in gmail, gmail says virus detected and will not allow me to attach it. I cannot attach the rmd as it contains some sensitive information but any ideas would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is it due to hyper links to external web pages? What happens when you knitr to pdf?

Comment: It looks like jquery ends up in the html file so there are tons of links in the comments of that javascript

Comment: Probably an issue.

Comment: Got it, I do have a couple links in there myself so I'll try generating without those and see if the jquery ones get past the virus scanner.

Comment: Are you using the DT package? (It'll be nice to provide a minimal reprex when asking questions) If so, you might have encountered this issue: https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/1080 which has been fixed, so you need to [update your R packages](https://yihui.org/en/2017/05/when-in-doubt-upgrade/).